# Timeout em processamento

Tags: delphi

Estou fazendo uma integração com SAT, quando não consigo a comunicação com o equipamento a aplicação trava. Existe alguma forma de eu estipular um tempo limite de espera para esse processo ser executado, cancelando a operação quando o *timeout* for atingido?

Comment: Cara, depende do processo, poderia detalhar melhor qual processo você quer cancelar?

Comment: no caso estou fazendo uma integração com SAT, quando não consigo a comunicação com o equipamento a aplicação trava.
Gostaria de estipular um timeout e parar o processo de comunicação quando o tempo for atingido.

Comment: Vou editar sua pergunta, adicionando essas informações. Existe alguma forma de você verificar se a comunicação foi realizada com sucesso? Se sim, basta colocar em um timer, não?

Comment: Quando não é possível fazer a comunicação, o processo fica travado no comando em que ativo o equipamento, sendo assim não tenho um retorno informando que a comunicação falhou.

Comment: Tente falar com o responsável do aparelho SAT, verifique o porque que ocorre esse travamento ao cancelar uma operação.

Answer (score 1):

Faça com thread e defina um timeout para a thread, assim você fará a chamada ao SAT dentro da thread e caso ocorra qualquer problema, o timeout da thread será alcançado e o sistema sairá.